# How to import com.google.cloud.datastore in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

i'm testing some exemples from google and I'm getting this error "the import com.google.cloud.datastore cannot be resolved".
How can i import com.google.datastore.* correctly in Eclipse?
I'm reading this http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.10.0/index.html but still not working.
(i've installed google cloud on Eclipse and other things are working, like hello app).
THX

Comment: did you try importing com.google.cloud dependency in your project?

Comment: yes but still not working. I think i have to import a kind of libs or similar. I've tried to modify pom file using Maven but nothing happens.

Comment: You may wish to attach code snippet or screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the dependency for the Google Cloud Datastore client library into your pom.xml. There's a `<dependencies>` section, add there:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-cloud</artifactId>
  <version>0.10.0-alpha</version>
</dependency>
```

(The above snippet is at the top of the page you linked).
After saving this, M2Eclipse should download and add the datastore jar to your project's classpath and then `import com.google.datastore.*` should work.

This should add the datastore jar to the Maven Dependencies of the project:
[image: Maven dependencies]

If you dig into it, you should see the `com.google.cloud.datastore.Datastore` class there:

[image]

Comment: yes it works for "com.google.datastore.*", but not for imports like: "import com.google.cloud.datastore.Datastore;
import com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreOptions;
import com.google.cloud.datastore.Entity;
import com.google.cloud.datastore.Key;"

Comment: Can you check if you can see the `google-cloud-datastore-0.10.0-beta.jar` under the Maven dependencies of the project?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to import the libs to your eclipse libs.